# Debug C unit test with Unity

Tags: c, unit-testing, unity-test-framework

I am writing some unit test on unity (http://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity/), however I am not getting the expected results and the test is failing when asserting.

Is there a way I can do printfs to do some debuggin on the mock callback functions?

For instance, the below assert is failing, I need to be able to know what I am getting in _myfunction_test to understand why this is failing:

```
myfunction_StubWithCallback((CMOCK_myfunction_CALLBACK) _myfunction_test);

TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_UINT16(5, Request_function(a, u8In, u8Out));
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not simply use a debugger with a breakpoint at the return statement of `_myfunction_test`?  If the code you write does not do what you expect, writing yet more code to debug it is perhaps a flawed proposition.

Comment: Just sprinkle printfs in `_myfunction_test` or anywhere else you want them. You do run the tests on a host system with standard IO, right?

Comment: I don't see how the assertion relates to `_myfunction_test`.